# OpsWorks Config Data: TypeError - Symbol as array index

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to use the IP of an instance on AWS OpsWorks in a Chef recipe, code looks like this:

```
variables(
  :db_host => (node[:scraper][:db_host] rescue nil),
  :db_user => (node[:scraper][:db_user] rescue nil),
  :db_pass => (node[:scraper][:db_pass] rescue nil),
  :db_name => (node[:scraper][:db_name] rescue nil),
  :beanstalk_host => (node[:opsworks][:layers][:admin][:instances].first[:private_ip])
)
```

But I get a `TypeError - Symbol as array index` error.

I'm not a Ruby developer, so I'm a bit lost with what to try. Even the docs list that syntax:

> The following example obtains the private IP address of the HAProxy layer's first instance:
>   `node[:opsworks][:layers][:lb][:instances].first[:private_ip]`

When I log the value of `node[:opsworks][:layers][:admin][:instances].first` I get:

`["admin1", {"elastic_ip"=>"54.221.245....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct: you can't use a symbol as an array index.

By the output of you last line, since it starts with a `[`, it is an array.

Most likely you are trying to index the dictionary on the second position of the array with the symbol `:private_ip`. In this case, the correct line is

```
node[:opsworks][:layers][:admin][:instances].first[1][:private_ip]
```

You need to go step by step in your mind. If `node[:opsworks][:layers][:admin][:instances].first` returns

```
["admin1", {"elastic_ip"=>"54.221.245....}]
```

Then `node[:opsworks][:layers][:admin][:instances].first[1]` will return

```
{"elastic_ip"=>"54.221.245....}
```

Comment: Thanks. The log confused me, wasn't sure if chef was somehow logging the key of the 'first' element of the hash as well as the data. 

Seems like either AWS documentation is incorrect about the data structure, or `.first` is returning data in a way I didn't see documented. Either way, it works, and I kind of understand what's going on.